# Customize Identity Server 4 Login UI for Hosted Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I have a solution based on the Visual Studio template that is successfully using IdentityServer4.

What think I understand is:

1. The IS4 integration implements endpoints at /authentication/{action}, e.g. authentication/login
2. IS4 routes that request to host/Identity/Account/Login.cshtml.  I have scaffolded identity so I can see that .cshtml file in my project.
3. The code-behind Login.cshtml.cs takes care of speaking with SignInManager, etc.
4. In the client project the "LoginDisplay.razor" component redirects to /authentication/login when I click the login button.  I presume that this is where step 1 above is invoked, which redirects to the location in step 2.

Fine.  Now, I want to customise the whole login UI.

From instructions at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-5.0 I can see that:

I can configure authentication paths to be anything I want.  For example:

```
builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization(options => {
    options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath = "security/login";
})
```

So, I have created a razor component to handle security/login:

```
@page "/security/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action">
    <LoggingIn>
        This is the new login page
    </LoggingIn>
</RemoteAuthenticatorView>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

My expectation was that after clicking "Login", I would be routed to the above and presented with a page that just said:

```
"This is the new login page"
```

and thought that from there, I would:

1. Customise the UI within the <LoggingIn> fragment.
2. Make a call to an API that would then replicate the logic in the scaffolded login.cshtml file that actually logs the user in.

That line of code from the login.cshtml.cs file looks like this:

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(
    Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

However, it seems that the razor component I created for /security/login is simply a 'transient' message that appears before being routed to the scaffolded login.csthml file.

So, to me, it seems that I am unable to actually change the physical page used to collect the user's credentials.  I am only able to change the transient screen that appears before the originally scaffolded login page is shown.

Does this mean that if I want a customised UI for logging in I need to directly edit the scaffolded page as opposed to creating a whole new UI in the WebAssembly project that calls an APIController that I create to take care of using SignInManager?

It would actually be a lot less work to do that than to take the approach of creating a Client-side UI that calls an API that I create, etc. so, with hindsight, editing the scaffolded cshtml file is probably the best way to go.  But am still confused as to what value is really being brought by being able to configure options.AuthenticationPaths.LogInPath.

Comment: That's not how the `<RemoteAuthenticatorView />` component works. It is simply a way to handle the content displayed between the various authentication states which normally reside on another server/platform (e.g., your Identity Server). You are better off looking into API-based authentication using OIDC and JWTs. You can still use the controller methods you described but you'd have to change the default flow of the Blazor WASM auth using your own `AuthenticationStateProvider`.

Comment: Thanks, Cory.  Indeed, I have move to API-based authentication with JWTs now so have full control.  Thanks.